# How do I set up two existing disks with identical contents as a single mirrored volume in Windows 7 without losing data?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, mirroring

I have two data disks that were, heretofore, in a mobo RAID configuration in Windows 7 (Ultimate, 64 bit).  They are now separate AHCI disks, visible in Computer Management.  How to I go about making them a single mirrored volume in Windows?

Note: The data is backed up up on two other separate disks, but it's a fair amount of work to do a restore (over 120'000 files, and I have to reset permissions).

Note2: Currently the two disks are identical, and I can use the content of either one for this.

**Edit 1**

I've converted one volume to dynamic and deleted the other, and rebooted just in case, but "Add Mirror" is still disabled.  Also, trying to create a "New Mirrored Volume" only offers the unallocated disk to include in the mirror.

[image]

**Edit 2**

The problem seems to be that, although the two disks are identical, the disk to be mirrored needs to be smaller than the disk to which you want to mirror. So I just decreased the partition size by 50 MB and then Add Mirror was available and I was able to mirror (in my screen shot) Disk 3 to Disk 0.  I suspect that I needed only a much smaller difference, perhaps 1-10 MB, but it's not worth my time to experiment to find the smallest difference that will mirror.

[image]

**Edit 3 (2014-03-31)**

Although making the existing disk smaller fixed the problem originally, having subsequently needed to re-mirror the disk at a later date, I then resized the disk back to it's full size and was able to successfully add the mirror - with identical hardware as when this question was posed. So it seems like a bug or quirk in Windows which may have been resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows 7 Pro and above.

For new Arrays:

Open up Computer Management, Disk Management. Right-click the unallocated drive and select "New Mirrored Volume"

Select the drives you want to use and edit the volume sizes if necessary. Click Next. You will be prompted to convert the disk to Dynamic disk. Select Yes to continue.

*Edit*

To mirror an existing drive:

Right click on the original partition -> Add Mirror; the designated mirror must be larger in size.

Comment: This only offers the disk which I deleted to be included in the new array.  And the remaining disk does has it's "Add Mirror" option grayed out.

Comment: See my edit - I can't add the unallocated volume.  On the disk with data the Add Mirror is grey, and on the other New Mirrored Volume only presents the unallocated volume for the mirror.

Comment: The problem seems to be that, although the two disks were identical, the disk to be mirrored needs to be smaller than the disk on which you are mirroring.  So I just decreased the partition size by 50 MB and then Add Mirror was available.

Comment: If you would like to edit your answer to indicate using "Add Mirror" on the allocated disk, instead of "New Mirrored Volume" on the unallocated disk, I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: @ Software Monkey That's what I call collaborative :-) Glad that I could at least point you in the right direction!

Comment: It seems like the problem like it was a bug, since fixed by MS; I had cause to recreate the mirror the other week and on a whim I resized the original partition to consume the entire disk.  Having done so, I was able to create the mirror using the other disk (all hardware identical to when this question was originally asked).